# Text not showing up in Jframes in my GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextfield

So I've been working on this program off and on for a few days, its a basic client server chat room. I'm trying to have it so that when you launch the client, the gui that pops up has text inside of the portnumber, servername, and textbox `JTextFields`. Yesterday this was the case but I've changed things and now the gui appears without text in the text fields. That code is in the displaysettings method which runs at the beginning of the try catch block.  Anyone know why it isn't working?

```
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class clienttry2 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();
    JButton send = new JButton("Send");
    JButton connect = new JButton("Connect");
    JLabel server = new JLabel("Server");
    JLabel port = new JLabel("Port");
    JButton disconnect = new JButton("Disconnect"); 
    static JTextField servername = new JTextField(10);
    static JTextField portnumber = new JTextField(10);
    static JTextField textbox = new JTextField(40);
    JTextArea chatbox = new JTextArea(20,45);

    static Boolean isconnected = false;
    static Boolean sending = false;
    static Socket server1;
    static ObjectInputStream in;
    static ObjectOutputStream out;

    public clienttry2(){
        setTitle("Chat Room");
        setLayout(new java.awt.FlowLayout());
        setSize(600,500);
        panel1.add(chatbox); //has all the chats
        panel2.add(textbox); //area to type new messages into
        panel2.add(send); send.addActionListener(this);//send button
        panel3.add(server);
        panel3.add(servername);
        panel3.add(port);       
        panel3.add(portnumber);
        panel3.add(connect); connect.addActionListener(this);
        panel3.add(disconnect); disconnect.addActionListener(this); disconnect.setEnabled(false);
        add(panel1);
        add(panel2);
        add(panel3);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
        Client display = new Client();
        display.setVisible(true);

        try{
            displaysettings();
            connect();
            setup();
            String message;
            message = (String) in.readObject();
            System.out.println(message);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void displaysettings() {
        portnumber.setText("3333");
        servername.setText("localhost");
        textbox.setText("This is where you type your messages to send to others on the server!");
    }

    private static void connect() throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        server1 = new Socket("localhost", 3333);
    }

    private static void setup() throws IOException {
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(server1.getOutputStream());
        out.flush();
        in = new ObjectInputStream(server1.getInputStream());
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(e.getSource()==connect)
        {
            System.out.println("connected");
            isconnected = true;
            connect.setEnabled(false);
            disconnect.setEnabled(true);
        }

        if(e.getSource()==send)
        {
            System.out.println("sending chat");
            sending = true;
        }
        if(e.getSource()==disconnect)
        {
            try {
                server1.close();
                out.close();
                isconnected = false;
                connect.setEnabled(true);
                disconnect.setEnabled(false);

            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you used a debugger?

Comment: You aren't posting any of your swing code to the Event Dispatch Thread like you should. Not sure if that's the actual problem, since I didn't examine the entire thing. Create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and who knows, you might stumble across the problem yourself.. If you don't find it, edit your MCVE into your post. I highly suggest studying Swing a little more, as well as looking into code design so you aren't mixing everything together, making it impossible to test things in isolation

Comment: I would recommend wrapping all the code in the main method into a Runnable passed to SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait so the UI is constructed on the EDT. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html

Answer (score -2):

`Swing` components will not update unless told to. After you set the text, call:

`textbox.repaint();`

to force the GUI to update.

Comment: Note that I tell you to do both simply because I never know which to use for the occasion, so I use both. If somebody edit's the correct one, I'll happily accept the edit.

Comment: `revalidate` is for when you add/remove a component to/from an already visible container. `repaint` just requests that the repaint manager repaints everything, not accounting for the component hierarchy. Not to mention, you don't need to revalidate when setting the text of a component, only when something gets added to it, removed from it, or causes it to change size. Can't say this is a proper answer; did you test it?

Comment: @VinceEmigh So `repaint` it is?

Comment: @VinceEmigh He adds the component, then he changes it, thus requiring the component to need an update. Check the constructor and `main` method to see what I'm talking about.

Comment: There should not be a need to call repaint() - calling setText should invoke the proper listeners to repaint the Component (presuming the call is on the EDT - which in the original code is not)

Comment: Class names should start with an upper case character and word within the class should also be capitalized. (clientry2 should be ClientTry2). It doesn't matter if this is a test class, follow the standards! Get rid of all the static variables. The text field is static, but the panel you add the text field to is not static??? I have no idea why you think some should be static but not others? Again, be consistent.